# How can I make Textmate always ignore the /log folder in the "Find in Project" search?

Tags: textmate

How can I make Textmate always ignore the /log folder in the "Find in Project" search?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a easier way to do it.

Go to Settings > Advanced > Folder References

And add |log| to the pattern.

- valid for TextMate 1

Comment: After you change the prefs reopen the project and log files will be filtered.

Answer (score 36):

Add the *log* folder to the `excludeInFolderSearch` option in your `~/.tm_properties` file, e.g.:

```
excludeInFolderSearch = "{$excludeInFolderSearch,$extraExcludes,log}"
```

Comment: Note that you may also place a `.tm_properties` file with project-specific settings such as this in your project directory.

Comment: This did not work for me on TextMate 2.0-beta.12. Please see my answer for a different solution.

Comment: This should be `excludeDirectories = "{$excludeDirectories,log}"`

Answer (score 10):

Other answers did not work for me on TextMate 2.0-beta.12. After many frustrating attempts, this line was able to exclude the log, vendor, tmp and .git directories from fuzzy searching.

`excludeInFileChooser = "{$excludeInFileChooser,log,vendor,tmp,.git}"`

I added this line to a `.tm_properties` file in my project directory. I verified that this also works if you decide to put the `.tm_properties` in the home directory.

Edit:

Use `excludeInFileChooser` for modifying search paths in Textmate's "Go To File" navigation feature, which is activated by `⌘T`.

Use `excludeInFolderSearch` for modifying paths when searching for text *within* the files of a directory, which is activated by either `⌘F` or `⌘↑F`

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Thank you! +1

Comment: This is the only relevant answer moving forward with TM2.

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for me.  What worked was adding the following in a .tm_properties file (project root)

```
excludeDirectories = "{node_modules,}"
```

No `$exclude` variable.  Add trailing comma.

Answer (score 3):

For **Textmate 2**:

Click on the top menu **Textmate**, then **Preferences**.

Navigate to the second tab, called **Projects**.

On the "**Exclude files matching**" just add 'log' to the end of the list, for example:

`{*.{o,pyc},Icon\r,CVS,_darcs,_MTN,\{arch\},blib,*\~.nib,tmp,log}`

This should do it, the `log` folder should no longer be searched, or used as match when opening a file.

Answer (score 2):

Use AckMate, https://github.com/protocool/AckMate and read hot to change the normal Find in Project Shift+Cmd+F here github.com/protocool/AckMate/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 1):

For TextMate2 it should be: `excludeDirectories = "{$excludeDirectories,log}"`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could explicitly tell Mate to look at a specific subset of folders.

```
~/project/mate app db models
```

Project find will be restricted to those folders.

Or to just remove the log dir you could add an alias to ~/.profile:

```
alias m="ls | grep -v 'log' | xargs mate"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove reference to log folder from project tree.

Also you may right click on *.log files and mark then as binary (they will not be searched).

http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/FindInProject